# Determine the time complexity when number of iterations are difficult to estimate

Tags: algorithm, c++11, computer-science

I have been in this situation many times where often its difficult to estimate the number of iterations and hence the close bound on worst case time complexity. Here is the problem :

You are given a number N. You keep adding the number N with its reverse, until you obtain the palindrome. e.g. 327 is given.

```
327 + 723 = 1050
1050 + 0501 = 1551
You stop
```

You can have following assumptions :

1. Solutions always exists
2. The max value of resulting palindrome will never cross 2^32 (4-bit int enough)

Here is my code :

```
unsigned long rev(unsigned long k)  //log k 
{
    unsigned long res = 0;
    while(k)
    {
        res = res * 10 + k%10;
        k = k/10;
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int t,iter;
    unsigned long n,res;

    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> n;
        iter = 0;

        while(1) //how many times this loop runs?
        {
            iter++;
            res = n + rev(n);
            if(res == rev(res)) //is a palindrome
                break;
            else
                n = res;
        }
        cout << iter << " " << res << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What would be the time complexity in this case?

This depends on how many times the inner while loop runs in worst case. The worst case happens when the number starts from 10 and jumps to the largest palindrome before 2^32. But how many jumps will it take is again difficult to estimate.

Perhaps in this case we can apply certain mathematics to estimate the iterations, but what if the situation is randomized by doing random algebra (+,-,*) before a palindrome is reached. How do we quote time complexity in those random situations?

Comment: Just speculating, but are you sure that inner loop finally stops? But I think you can say that approximating number of loops is something that we can do normally mathematically, and if we cannot, we use worst case senario. because if we improve worst case, we can be sure everything is OK. But in your code, I'm not sure that inner loop will stop for any starting number, and this can be bad. I have not analyzed algorithm completely, so I can be completely wrong.

Comment: You need to find the mathematical relationship under the problem, this is by no way a trivial task. A probabilistic approach is generally used when the relationship is hard to tackle.

Comment: When you need to use such kind of loop (while(1)/break) it is a good sign that complexity is hard to find...

Comment: The worst case complexity is about 32. Because every time you kinda multiply it by 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot estimate the time complexity, because it cannot be proven (yet) that the algorithm always terminates.

The so called [Lychrel numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number) are the numbers where the algorithm doesn't terminate. 196 is the most famous one. It is not proven that the algorithm never terminates for 196 or other Lychrel numbers, but obviously noone could find a solution yet, so it is assumed that Lychrel numbers are existing and the algorithm is not terminating if we start with those numbers.

Comment: Haha, I had a feeling that this method may never finish. Just a feeling...It is fun to see your feeling become true. :D I didn't know about Lychrel numbers. :)

Comment: @maraca : Thanks for pointing about Lychrel numbers. Nice takeway from this question